# Beginner SQL inner join query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a homework question that I am totally stuck on, basically I have to write an SQL statement that returns a data set with all airports in a certain city. The data set must show:
City name, Country, Airport code, latitude, longitude.

So far I have come closest with this:

```
SELECT 
       City.name as city,
       Country.name as country, 
       Airport.code,
       Airport.latitude,
       Airport.longitude
FROM Country, Airport, City
INNER JOIN Airport a1
ON City.id = a1.city
INNER JOIN Country c1
ON City.country = c1.id
WHERE Airport.city = 12;
```

This brings up the correct airport info but the city and country data is showing all the countries and cities in the table. Also City.country references Country.id if that makes a difference in this case.
Any info to point me in the right direction going forward would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your `FROM` clause to `FROM City` only

Comment: Show some sample table data of your query

Comment: Could you also show the fields and contents of those tables as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you gave is really doing *two* joins. First, you're joining via the comma-delimited list under your `FROM` clause. That's a legacy way of doing it, so you were right to use the other way. Simply remove the tables aside from `City` (Which I pick, of course, because the others are introduced via separate `INNER JOIN` clauses) there, and it should work.

```
SELECT 
   City.name as city,
   c1.name as country, 
   a1.code,
   a1.latitude,
   a1.longitude
FROM City
    INNER JOIN Airport a1 ON City.id = a1.city
    INNER JOIN Country c1 ON City.country = c1.id
WHERE a1.city = 12;
```

You can also review [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=SQL.105).aspx) on using the `INNER JOIN` syntax.

I'd be tempted to remove your alias-usage, just since I tend to think it removes some readability if it's not completely necessary (it would be if you had subqueries), but I preserved it since you had it in your original question.

Comment: I am sure you meant `From City` instead of `From Country` :)

Comment: @R.T. I did! Thanks for catching that and fixing it for me. Gotta hate silly typos like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had tried this but I kept getting the [#1054 - Unknown column 'Country.name' in 'field list'] error.

Comment: @user3539718 Well, is there a column called `name` in your `Country` table? I took that from your original query...

Comment: Yes it does have a name column, and for some reason I only avoid the error by having my list under FROM  in the exact order I have it above.

Comment: @user3539718 Ohh, wait, sorry. I forgot you added in table aliases. Alright. I've edited my answer.